# Does SharePoint support simultaneous reviewers?

Tags: collaboration

I'm new to SharePoint so maybe this is a silly question:

Can SharePoint be used to allow multiple reviewers to annotate a Word document at the same time?

The idea being that each reviewer can see the other comments as they are made and there is some sort of tooling to ensure that:

1. Each reviewer has seen all the comments.
2. The comments are tracked across any forthcoming document revisions.

At work we use source code review tools that allow such collaborative reviewing, and it's great workflow.

I found the tool [Collaborator](http://smartbear.com/products/software-development/code-review) from SmartBear, but it's Word support is so-so and we already use SharePoint heavily for Office related documents.

Can this be done directly with SharePoint?

**Edit:**  Using the 2010 versions of SharePoint and Office.

Thank you

Comment: What specific versions of Office and SharePoint are you working with?

Comment: @DaveWise 2010 on both.  Question updated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 and Office 2010 fully support simultaneous [collaboration/co-authoring](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/document-collaboration-and-co-authoring-HA101812148.aspx) in Word but I am not aware of any tool that can ensure your point #1.  Point #2 is done automatically in Word using the Track revisions option but can be extended by enabling versioning in the SharePoint document Library itself.

Beyond that, SharePoint supports several types of workflows that can be created to route the document through all reviewers in sequence.